# disabling click of controls

Tags: jquery-ui

Hi
I am using **jQuery-ui-1.8.7-custom.js** dialog box. Now i want when the dialog box will open then the user will not be able to click on any control of page.

Please give me solution.

Thanks & Regards,

Munish Gautam

Answer (score 0):

Use modal config option when you are displaying the dialog.
Refer to http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-modal

Answer (score 0):

Pass in `modal: true`:

```
dialog({ modal: true })
```